# Makefile using m4 to build Dockerfiles is not rebuilding

Tags: docker, makefile, m4

I have 6 different Dockerfiles, that look very similar, so I used m4 and include to build them from snippets.

I don't know much about using Makefile's for purposes other than C++, and I have a problem with make not rebuilding when a m4 file changed, and not running iterative copy operations unless the target changed.

Please provide some input on better practices and help?

See: https://github.com/ptr727/NxWitness/tree/master/Make

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := check

# Even if the m4 files changed make still reports up to date?
INPUTS = $(wildcard ${CURDIR}/*.m4)
OUTPUTS = $(addsuffix .dockerfile, $(basename $(INPUTS)))
# Why does the output look funky?
TARGETS = $(abspath ${CURDIR}/..)/$(basename $(notdir $(INPUTS)))/Dockerfile

%.dockerfile : %.m4
    m4 $< > $@

check:
    @echo "INPUTS = $(INPUTS)"
    @echo "OUTPUTS = $(OUTPUTS)"
    @echo "TARGETS = $(TARGETS)"

create: $(OUTPUTS)

clean:
    -rm *.dockerfile $(OUTPUTS)

# Why does make report up to date even after clean?
# $(foreach file, $(OUTPUTS), $(cp $(file) $(abspath ${CURDIR}/..)/$(basename $(notdir $(file)))/Dockerfile))
replace:
    cp DWSpectrum.dockerfile ../DWSpectrum/Dockerfile
    cp DWSpectrum-LSIO.dockerfile ../DWSpectrum-LSIO/Dockerfile
    cp NxWitness.dockerfile ../NxWitness/Dockerfile
    cp NxWitness-LSIO.dockerfile ../NxWitness-LSIO/Dockerfile
    cp NxMeta.dockerfile ../NxMeta/Dockerfile
    cp NxMeta-LSIO.dockerfile ../NxMeta-LSIO/Dockerfile

build:
    docker build -f ../DWSpectrum/Dockerfile ../DWSpectrum
    docker build -f ../DWSpectrum-LSIO/Dockerfile ../DWSpectrum-LSIO
    docker build -f ../NxWitness/Dockerfile ../NxWitness
    docker build -f ../NxWitness-LSIO/Dockerfile ../NxWitness-LSIO
    docker build -f ../NxMeta/Dockerfile ../NxMeta
    docker build -f ../NxMeta-LSIO/Dockerfile ../NxMeta-LSIO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Dockerfile, you have Make targets like `build` and `replace` that don't correspond to real files.  Those will always be considered out-of-date and need to be rebuilt, even if their inputs haven't changed.  (In GNU Make, marking them as `.PHONY:` is good practice.)

If you have some task, like building a Docker image, that doesn't directly generate a file on its own, a useful technique is to put some sort of "marker" file to record that it's done.  After you do the task, `touch` the marker file.  If one of its inputs has changed, it will appear newer than the marker file, and will cause Docker to rebuild the file.

```
%/.docker-build: %/Dockerfile
        docker build $(dir $@)
        touch "$@"
```

You can use similar pattern syntax to generate the Dockerfiles from the m4 files.  (This is almost exactly the rule you have above, but with a different target.)

```
%/Dockerfile: %.m4
        m4 $< >$@
```

If you have a list of directories

```
DIRS := DWSpectrum DWSpectrum-LSIO NxWitness NxWitness-LSIO NxMeta NxMeta-LSIO
```

then you can have the "build" target just depend on the marker files

```
.PHONY: build
build: $(DIRS:%=%/.docker-build)
```

and the "clean" rule should clean up everything we generated

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -f $(DIRS:%=%/.docker-build)
        rm -f $(DIRS:%=%/Dockerfile)
```

I've used two syntaxes here that replace your function calls and `foreach` loops.  When building a rule, if `%` is on both sides of a rule, it can be replaced by an identical string to make a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules); Make knows that `DWSpectrum/.docker-build` can be built from `DWSpectrum/Dockerfile` via this rule.  `$(DIRS:%=%/Dockerfile)` is a [substitution reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html#Substitution-Refs); for each item in `$(DIRS)` that matches the pattern `%` (that is, every item) replace it with the matched string plus the `/Dockerfile` suffix.

Comment: Thank you, your approach uses the predefined directory names, vs. iterating all m4 files and creating output directories based on m4 files, could you show such an example? I did get your version working, but I had to put ../ in front of the directory names, as the directories are one level up. With where the docker build is now, it is not obvious to me how to -t tag the build, so that I can later in clean docker image rm tag the image?

Comment: In the rule that runs `docker build`, the (GNU) Make variable `$*` should have the name of the directory that contains the `Dockerfile`, or `$@` will be the name of the stamp file; you can manipulate these as needed to build a `docker build -t` option.  You could use something like your existing `wildcard` invocation to find the directory names if you wanted, perhaps something like `DIRS := $(subst .m4,,$(wildcard *.m4))`.